# Sharing a reference between objects

Tags: c#, reference

I want to have multiple objects share a reference through a private field, such that any of the objects can assign to the field, and the updated field will be seen by other objects sharing that reference. What I was originally hoping to do was this:

```
class SomeObject
{
    private ref DataObject _data;
    public SomeObject(ref DataObject data)
    {
         _data = ref data; // or something similar
    }

    public ChangeData(DataObject newData)
    {
         _data = data;
         // at this point, *other* SomeObject instances that were
         // created with the same reference should also have _data == newData
    }
}
```

But of course you can't use `ref` that way: `ref` is only for method parameters. And a static field won't work, since not *all* `SomeObject` instances should refer to the same object---rather, the object in question should be set in the constructor.

Obviously I could solve this by just adding a simple wrapper class. But is there a better way? Is there some kind of `SharedReference<T>` class that I can use?

**Update**, since most of the answers misunderstood what I was asking. I know that the `_data` field contains a *reference* to the original `DataObject`. What I want is another level of indirection. I want to be able to *change which object I'm pointing to* in one instance, and have the new value be picked up by other instances that were created with the same reference. As the updated code sample shows, I want to assign to `_data`, and effectively change the value of `_data` in other instances.

Comment: How do you define which objects *share* the reference and which have their own instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any class that you can use for this, but I seems quite easy to implement your own `SharedReference<T>` class.

Something like this:

```
public sealed class SharedReference<T>
    where T : class
{
    public T Reference
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can use this. I just added an `implicit operator T` for extra convenience.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you simply provide a reference to the object without the `ref` keyword, you will get the behaviour you want.  Using `ref` is actually passing a reference to a reference (pointer to a pointer), so unless you want to `null` someone else's reference, it won't be of any use to you.</strike>

**Update:** Sorry I didn't spot that you wanted to re-assign a completely new object into the field and have that reflected throughout.  You are best actually creating either a wrapper class to contain the object *state* and modify that, or a common event that all instances can subscribe to such that when you want to change the object, fire the event with the new object inside it and have each instance update it's own internal reference.

Alternatively, use the Singleton pattern - everyone accesses a publicly available static reference, but unlike the traditional Singleton, you let them change the reference if they want to - so everyone can see the change.  This also has the benefit that the objects don't need internal references.

Alternatively again, have the data class expose a method allowing it to consume another data class and copy its state across - like cloning.

Comment: Nope - he wants to reassign the field completely

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use an array of shared objects, and reassign the array elements:

```
class SomeObject
{
    // you probably want to make this readonly
    private readonly DataObject[] _data;     

    public SomeObject(DataObject[] data)
    {
         _data = data;
    }

    public void ChangeData(DataObject newData)
    {
        _data[0] = o;
    }

    // and you could define your own accessor property...
    private DataObject Data
    {
        get { return _data[0]; }
        set { _data[0] = value; }
    }
}
```

Apart from that, I think you'll need to define your own 'holder' class & use that

Comment: This is the first answer that actually understood the question. Thanks :).

Comment: @JS Bangs I didn't spot the assignment part - I immediately read "change state" lol, I've modified my answer.  Using an array for this is not a very good way to go IMO, its less readable that the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

<del>In C#,</del>

```
class SomeObject
{
    private DataObject _data;
    public SomeObject(DataObject data)
    {
         _data = data;
    }
}
```

in fact does exactly what you want, if DataObject is a Reference Type, which is true for all classes.

Please disregard this answer since I misunderstood the initial question.
Other answers here cover the topic fully.

Comment: Nope - he wants to reassign the field completely

Comment: @thecoop please remove the negative vote. The question was updated _after_ my post, and the initial question was ambiguous. I will update my answer shortly

Comment: You can delete your own posts - there should be a 'delete' link between 'edit' and 'flag'